# RxJava-file and operator chaining

Tags: java-8, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm trying to reactively tail a log file using [RxJava-File](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-file):

```
    File file = new File(".\\server.log");
    Observable<String> newLines =
            FileObservable.tailer()
                    .file(file)
                    .startPosition(file.length())
                    .sampleTimeMs(1000)
                    .chunkSize(8192)
                    .utf8()
                    .tailText();

    newLines.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

and it works as expected.
But as soon as I try to chain some more operators, I get problems. For instance, changing to

```
  newLines.filter(LogfileWatcher::error).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

(where `error()` is a simple function `String -> Boolean`) I get output only after the first append to the file, but not the subsequent ones.
Similar problems appear when using `window()` or several other operators.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: interesting, I'll have a look. rxjava-file was an early creation of mine, might be time to review it a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backpressure support had to be fixed in *rxjava-file* and your test case is reported to be working as of *rxjava-file* 0.3.3 on Maven Central.