# How to tail a file with rx-java?

Tags: multithreading, observable, rx-java, reactive-programming, observer-pattern

Using the `rx-java` package, how can I [tail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32646260/262852) a file?

code:

```
package tail;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FileUtils {

    public FileUtils() {
    }

    public void readFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        StringBuilder resultStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader br
                = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                resultStringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(resultStringBuilder);
    }

}
```

I'd want to parse [each line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20663255/262852) as its written to the file.  First, need an [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/557844/262852) to `tail -f foo.log` from Java.

Comment: Did you look into using: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/TailerListenerAdapter.html#handle-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about using *RxJava* specifically. But you can take a general Java solution and combine with *RxJava*. This of course depends on how you want to be informed.

One basic option is to tail the file using an open `InputStream` (or some stream wrapper classes or reader class).
Using a running thread, you can wait on the file with `InputStream.read` or sample the amount of new bytes with `InputStream.available`. In *RxJava* you can use the *IO* scheduler. After finishing to read an entire line, just invoke some observers from the thread.

In core Java, it could look something like:

```
class ObserveTask implements Runnable {

    private File file;
    private Listener listener;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file); 
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream)) {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                listener.onNewLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now just run the task:

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newThread();
Scheduler.Worker worker = scheduler.createWorker();
worker.schedule(new ObserveTask());
```

Of course this is just a basic example.

You can split the task to parts, where each run, a check is made for the bytes, while the stream remains open. Of course this is dangerous, since leaving a stream open like that might end in leaking.

A more advanced solution can include using [`WatchService`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio2-watchservice).